# How find shortcut name by program name?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio, shortcut-file

Is there some way to find the name of a shortcut (present on desktop) through the associated program name?

Ex:

Filename:

- *C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe*

and result in:

- *C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Firefox.lnk*

I found [something near to this](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,1709.msg225290.html#msg225290), but is made the opposite way (returns the associated program name by shortcut name).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The application knows nothing about shortcuts that are created to point to it, so this isn't possible. You'd have to iterate every file in the user's Desktop folder looking for shortcut files, open them using `IShellLink`, and look to see if they launched the application you're looking to find. Here's an example of doing so. You'll need to add `ShellAPI` to your `uses` clause. `FileName` is the fully qualified name of the shortcut file.

```
function GetLinkPath(const FileName: WideString): String;
var
  ShellLink: IShellLink;
  Path: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  Result := '';
  ShellLink := CreateComObject(CLSID_ShellLink) as IShellLink;
  if (ShellLink as IPersistFile).Load(PWideChar(FileName), STGM_READ) = 0 then
  begin
    if ShellLink.GetPath(Path, MAX_PATH, nil, SLGP_SHORTPATH) = 0 then
      Result := Path;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: *"`open them`"*, i not understood. How it? you wanted say: execute them? Give a better explanation about this please.